# Como simplificar um foreach por uma expressão Linq - Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Desempenho não é um problema no meu projeto, eu quero saber uma substituição mais simples e legível pro meu foreach usando Linq e Lambda (se possível).

```
// 'DiscoVirtual' é uma classe
// 'this.HDs' é um 'List<DiscoVirtual>'
// 'Atual' e 'Novo' são instâncias de 'DiscoVirtual'

foreach (DiscoVirtual d in this.HDs)
{
    if (d == Atual)
    {
        this.HDs.Remove(Atual);
        if (Novo != null) this.HDs.Add(Novo);
    }
}
```

Além do mas, se `Novo` for `null` eu só quero que remova `Atual` (eu complementei o código).

Comment: A propriedade `HDs` tem setter ou só tem getter?

Comment: Para esclarecer, a intenção do código é substituir o disco `Actual` pelo `Novo`? E se a lista não contiver `Actual`, não acontece nada?

Comment: Ambos: `{ get; private set; }`. Este trecho está dentro da classe.

Comment: `Atual` já faz pate da lista `this.HDs`. Não é possível não estar. Eu quero trocar a referência de `Atual` pela referência de `Novo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse código não pode ser convertido directamente para LINQ porque tem um estilo imperativo e não é funcional.

Por outras palavras, LINQ promote um estilo funcional (sem efeitos secundários, transparência referencial, e com dados imutáveis), e esse código viola todas estas 3 regras ao alterar o estado da lista com `Add` e `Remove`.

Para empregar um estilo funcional, devemos, a partir da lista actual de `HDs`, calcular uma *nova* lista, deixando a original intacta.

Depois, substituimos a lista HDs pela nova lista.

```
HDs = HDs.Select(hd => hd == Actual? Novo : hd).ToList();
```